# run gdrive as a command in linux script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I wrote a script that makes backup from database each day at particular time and I tried to save that file on google drive but outside of script command execute properly against inside it doesn't work. I used `sudo -u root` at the begining of line but still doesn't work

```
sudo -u root gdrive upload /var/www/html/soft/backups/db_backup_27_02_2018_17_45_01.gz
```

Is there any recommendation ?

Comment: _Doesn't work_ means nothing, if you have error, tell us. An if you want to run a commans as root, use : `sudo gdrive upload /var/www/html/soft/backups/db_backup_27_02_2018_17_45_01.gz` But as far of gdrive is to sync a google storage, why even on earth are you trying to use root account ???!!!

Comment: Run `which gdrive` to get the full path, then use the full path in your script.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: `which` search executables in `PATH`, so better use `find /home /bin /usr -name 'gdrive*' 2>/dev/null` and if `gdrive` is a script in current dir : `./gdrive` If you know the full PATH, then put in in your script

Comment: @GillesQuenot It should be found on OP's PATH because his command works outside the script.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Good catch